# Removing a coat closet in a single-story 2001 build. Does this look like load-bearing to you guys?

Tags: walls, studs, load

Removing a coat closet in a single-story 2001 build. Does this look like load-bearing to you guys?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is unlikely to be load bearing.  It is more likely that the wall behind the closet is load bearing.

Comment: I would think if it was load bearing it would have a proper header, oriented vertically, not just a single 2x4 laid flat.